# How do I lock a branch from being merged with master?

Tags: git, github, branch

I have a github repository which has 3 branches: development, design and master. I don't use design anymore, as I used it to make my UI before I created development. My question is if I can make it so that accidentally merging design with master can not happen as in 'locking the branch in place'.

The reason that I still need it, is because it is an assignment for school, so I would rather keep it if I need it again.

I've tried looking it up, but I could not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I you *really* want to make sure no merge will ever take place...

- create a new GitHub repository
- push the two working branches to it
- clone it elsewhere and resume your work in that new cloned repository, which has only two branches.

Comment: I meant that I wanted it to be in the same repository, but that would work the same as putting the old design branch into a new repository. So there isn't any way to do it in one repository?